# Reading memory in correct order Need some help

Tags: c, algorithm

We are storing some sort of records in memory location as follows

```
----------------------------------------------
|EventID | Timestamp | Variable Data | Length  |
----------------------------------------------
```

Lengths of these fields are as follows

EventID+ timestamp is 12 bytes
Length Fields is 4 bytes , it indicates the length of data field.

Millions of such records are placed one after the other & I have a pointer pointing to the current index, so If I want to read all the records I go like this I read 4 bytes right to left & I fetch that particular record & doing this iteratively I read the complete memory space. But the problem with this method is that It reads records in the reverse order as compared to the order in which to they were entered.

I need to device a method which will allow me to read this memory records in the same order they were entered with minimal space complexity.

Comment: What is "(minimal) space complexity"? (actually a cool term)

Comment: need to use minimum amount of extra space

Comment: Can you swap `Data` and `Length` fields? This is uncommon layout of a row.

Comment: unfortunately no I dont have access to the write function library :(

Comment: Is your "current index" an index to the left (i.e. to the start of `EventID`), or right (i.e. the end of `Length`)? There doesn't seem to be a way to get the data reliably from left-to-right.

Comment: How write function library output this data? Is it some sort of buffer with start ptr and size?

Comment: current index is the on the right side..

Comment: yes its a buffer , library outpts data in reverse order of entry.. 
thats what I am looking to change

Comment: So, the problem here is how to effectively reverse a set of a records which have different size, right?

Comment: yes with the above memory layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the variable length data section comes before the length, it will be impossible to read data starting with the beginning memory address.  Assuming no changes can be made to architecture or storage, one possible option is to use your current system to build an index of the variable data lenghts.  Then, once you reach the beginning of the data you would then read the records in the correct order - using the previous built index to determine variable data length.

However, you mention this dataset contains millions of records.  Thus storing an index of all variable data lengths before processing may not be feasible.  One such solution to this problem would be to index only every other entry, or every fourth, eight, etc... depending upon your specific requirements.  Then you could start at each indexed record, work backwards temporarily saving the data lengths until you reach a record you havn't processed.  Then work forward again using this saved data.

For example, let's say you index every 8 records your first pass. Then, you would start at record 8 and save the length of that record.  Then go to 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1.  Now you've saved the next 8 lenghts.  So process record 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, and 8.  Now, you don't know the length of 9 - so jump to 16.  Then record 16, 15, 14, .., 9 lengths.  Then again as before process 9, 10, 11 ... 16.  Now repeat.

Comment: This "partial indexing" is quite interesting.

Comment: isnt it same as storing legths of all the records ?

Comment: No, you could only store 1/8th or 1/16th of them (or whatever fraction). Its more compute-intensive than a full index, but requires less memory.

Comment: not exactly because you're not storing them all at once. Let's say you have 2,000,000 records and you store every 8. The most lenghts you would store at any time are the original pass of every other 8, plus a maximum of 7 temporarily.  So a total of 250007.  The 7 are temporary, because after indexing back to a record already processed, you move to the next known length from your initial index and reuse the 7 temporarily lengths again.

Comment: this approach looks good .. I will try this one .. 
any other approaches come to mind ?

Answer (score 4):

I have another great solution for you!

1. Read your records in reverse order (end to beginning) and swap in-memory values for  `EventID` and `Length` fields.
2. When access rows, just keep in mind the new layout: `Length` | `Timestamp` | `Data` | `EventID`

Comment: yeah I considered that but doing 2/3 memcopy for per record for millions records seems to be expensive .. what do yo think

Comment: I believe this will the fastest solution we have - the CPU's cache helps. Creating an additional index map will be more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Try to 'reverse' records order while fetching at first, and then make a second fetch using the same process (allocate same memory amount to reverse).

As the variable data has variable length, and the length value in last position, I see no way to get this fetching from left to right.

Comment: I am not copying the records one by one am doing memcpy as I need to quickly free the lock on the buffer also. 

but it seems like a good idea, but space complexity is compromised. It will require another buffer of the same size..

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to find the end of a row with no additional memory.

1. All `EventID` fall into definite range, and could be sequential
2. All `Timestamp` have a definite range too (say, from 2009/09/09 through 2011/11/11)
3. `Length`, `EventID`, and `Timestamp` are adjacent between two rows and have fixed length of 16 bytes in total (4 for length, 4 for eventID, and 8 for timestamp).

Under these considerations you could write a function that searches the end of a row, e.g.

```
byte* FindNextRow(byte* rowStart, byte* memBlockEnd,
                 DWORD minEventID, DWORD maxEventID,
                 QWORD minTimestamp, QWORD maxTimestamp)
{
  long bytesAvail = (long)(memBlockEnd - rowStart) - 4;
  byte* ptr = rowStart + 12; // move to 'data'

  for (long i = 0; i < bytesAvail; i++, ptr++) {

    long length = *(long*)(ptr);

    // check if this is the last row
    if (ptr + 4 == memBlockEnd)
      return memBlockEnd;

    // try to find candidate for 'length' field first
    if (rowStart + 12 != ptr - length)
      continue;

    // then check 'EventID' and 'Timestamp' for the next row
    DWORD eventID = *(DWORD*)(ptr + 4);
    if (eventID < minEventID || eventID > maxEventID)
      continue; // you might add additional check on a sequence: eventID + 1 == *(DWORD*)(rowStart);

    QWORD timestamp = *(QWORD*)(ptr + 8);
    if (timestamp < minTimestamp || timestamp > maxTimestamp)
      continue; // you might add additional check on a sequence: timestamp > *(QWORD*)(rowStart + 4);

    // this is the match
    return ptr + 4;
  }
}
```

WARNING: this will not guarantee the correctness, but you could try to find a workaround this way.

Answer (score 0):

Is allocating one pointer (in a 32 bits machine, usually 4 bytes) per message acceptable to you?

If it is, you could, starting from the end:

1. Read length at current position - 4
2. Get the pointer to the 1st byte of event id with: current position - 4 - length - 12
3. Resize the pointer array if needed
4. Store that pointer in the array
5. Repeat from 1

Of course, you would need to realloc() as the pointer array grows (no need to realloc every time, do it in chunks).

I am assuming you are treating them as a char array, so char pointer difference of contiguous elements (n and n-1) would give you the size of the entire message.

This wastes memory. I know you don't want to, but if you can't do like Opillect said, swapping EventID and Length fields because they have different sizes, this seems like a good way to do it.